# aiohttp с использование socks

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

Нужно использовать socks4/5, решил воспользоваться библиотекой aiosocks.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aiosocks
from aiosocks.connector import ProxyConnector, ProxyClientRequest

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url,  proxy='socks4://1.1.1.1:4145', verify=False) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    conn = ProxyConnector(remote_resolve=True)
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn, request_class=ProxyClientRequest) as session:
        html = await fetch(session, "http://exemple.com")
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Выдает следующие ошибке:

```
"aiosocks\connector.py", line 4, in <module>
    from aiohttp.client_exceptions import certificate_errors, ssl_errors
ImportError: cannot import name 'certificate_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rt.py", line 365, in <module>
    from aiosocks.connector import ProxyConnector, ProxyClientRequest
  File "aiosocks\connector.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError('aiosocks.SocksConnector require aiohttp library')
ImportError: aiosocks.SocksConnector require aiohttp library
```

Прокси рабочие, код взят с примера в их. Как исправить ситуацию? Или есть другие решение проблемы?

Comment: `ImportError: aiosocks.SocksConnector require aiohttp library`. А aiohttp установлен?

Comment: @gil9red, да. Без проксей всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Пакет `aiosocks` вроде как утратил совместимость с aiohttp 3.4+

Попробуйте
 https://github.com/romis2012/aiohttp-socks